# How much energy do Li-Ions/Li-Pos have below 3.2V threshold?

Tags: battery-operated, lipo, battery-chemistry, drone

How much energy does a battery still have when a protection chip disconnects it? I know that such discharging kills the battery, but in some cases it would be useful. For example, in drones: when you don’t have enough power to land it safely, you could disable the protection controller and land it using this rest power. You don’t loose the whole drone, only the battery. Also it would be useful in cell phones in emergencies.

Comment: You can do more harm than good draining it below 3.2

Comment: There is such a small percentage of energy available that designing a system that provide adequate reserve is a far better idea. You may get a few percent. Perhaps 5% depending on C discharge rate. The battery life will be substantially shortened if you constantly discharge into this area. [[The drone life may be substantially shortened if you are not able to do so when needed :-) ]]

Comment: A good reason not to do this is that overdischarge can cause invisible damage that won't be apparent until the next time you (or someone else) tries to charge it... and it catches fire.

Answer (score 0):

This information can be gleaned from a battery discharge curve.

There is not a lot of power left in Lithium battery once it has discharged down to 3.2V .  The curve drops down steeply around 3.2V .

[image]